# $L^p$-continuity for discrete linear causal systems

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, stability, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $p \in [1, +\infty)$, $(b_0(n)), \dots (b_m(n)), (a_1(n)), \dots, (a_m(n))$ suitable sequences of real numbers and consider the map $\phi: \ell^p \to \ell^p$, $x \mapsto y$ defined by:
\begin{equation}
y(n) + a_1(n) y(n - 1) + \dots + a_m(n) y(n - m) = b_0(n) x(n) + \dots + b_m(n) x(n - m),
\end{equation}
where it is understood $x(n) = y(n) = 0$ for $n < 0$. Such a map is called, in the context of dynamical systems, a *linear time-varying causal system*.

It is well known that $\ell^p \subset \ell^q$ for $p \leq q \leq + \infty$, so we can endow $\ell^p$ with the $q$-norm for every $q \geq p$. How can you compare continuity/boundedness of $\phi$ for different $q$-norms? Here is what I understood so far:

1. For time-invariant systems, i.e if $a_i(n)$ and $b_j(n)$ do not depend on $n$, $\phi$ is continuous for every $q$-norm if and only if the solutions of $1 + a_1 z^{-1} + \dots + a_m z^{-m} = 0$ lie (strictly) inside the unit circle. This is a classical result for $p = +\infty$ (the so-called *BIBO-stability*), but it is easy to prove also for $p < + \infty$.
2. In the general case, one can also see that BIBO-stability holds when $|a_1(n)| + \dots |a_m(n)| \leq C < 1$. However, I think that less restrictive criteria hold, and I have no information on the $q < +\infty$ situation.

It would also be interesting to compare this problem to the analogous continuous-time one.

Thank you in advance.